# How to call different methods only once, at different times?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, action, coroutine

I'm trying to use Actions and Events, Inumerators and Coroutines, but I'm getting so confused.

The goal: Get MoveCubes() to run once for 3 seconds, and then get LerpSine() to run once for 3 seconds.

The seconds are being tracked by `CountdownTimer.cs`. Then `SkinnedMeshSpawn.cs` interacts with it.

CountdownTimer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    float currentTime = 0f;
    float startingTime = 10f;
    public static event Action RaiseReady;
    public static event Action RaiseReady2;
    public SkinnedMeshSpawn SkinnedMeshSpawn;

    void Start()
    {
        currentTime = startingTime;     
        StartCoroutine(UpdateCoroutine());
    }

    IEnumerator UpdateCoroutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            SkinnedMeshSpawn.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshSpawn>().MoveCubes();
            currentTime -= 1 * Time.deltaTime; //does it each frame
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(currentTime);

            if (n == 7)
            {
                RaiseReady?.Invoke();
                RaiseReady = null; // clean the event
                yield break; // Kills the coroutine
            }
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator UpdateCoroutine2()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            SkinnedMeshSpawn.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshSpawn>().LerpSine();
            currentTime -= 1 * Time.deltaTime; //does it each frame
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(currentTime);

            if (n == 4)
            {
                RaiseReady2?.Invoke();
                RaiseReady2 = null; // clean the event
                yield break; // Kills the coroutine

            }
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

SkinnedMeshSpawn:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(SkinnedMeshRenderer))]
public class SkinnedMeshSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject CubePrefab;
    public GameObject[] objects;
    SkinnedMesh mesh;
    public Rigidbody cubePrefabRb;

    public Vector3[] verts;

    int runOnce = 1;

    void Awake()
    {
        mesh = GetComponent<SkinnedMesh>();
        verts = new Vector3[mesh.vertexCount];
    }
    void Start()
    {
        verts = mesh.vertices;

        CountdownTimer.RaiseReady += CountdownTimer_RaiseReady;
        CountdownTimer.RaiseReady2 += CountdownTimer_RaiseReady2;

        mesh.OnResultsReady += DrawVertices;
    }
    void CountdownTimer_RaiseReady()
    {
        Debug.Log("Done");
        CountdownTimer.RaiseReady -= CountdownTimer_RaiseReady; // Remove listener though the other class is already clearing it
    }

    private void CountdownTimer_RaiseReady2()
    {
        Debug.Log("Done2");
        CountdownTimer.RaiseReady2 -= CountdownTimer_RaiseReady; // Remove listener though the other class is already clearing it
    }

    void DrawVertices(SkinnedMesh mesh)
    {
        if (runOnce == 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mesh.vertexCount; i++)
            {
                Vector3 position = verts[i];
                var cubeClone = Instantiate(CubePrefab, position, transform.rotation);
                cubeClone.tag = "CubePFInst";
            }
            runOnce = 0;
        }
    }


    public void MoveCubes()
    {
        if (runOnce == 0)
        {
            objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("CubePFInst");

            for (int i = 0; i < mesh.vertexCount; i++)
            {
                Vector3 position = verts[i];
                cubePrefabRb = objects[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                cubePrefabRb.MovePosition(Vector3.Lerp(position, position, Time.deltaTime * 6));
            }
        }
    }

    public void LerpSine()
    {
        Debug.Log("LerpSine");
    }
}
```

The most I've been able to accomplish so far is getting the `UpdateCoroutine2` to be called and having `Done2` print to Log, but `LerpSine` gets printed repeatedly as if I'm starting the coroutine with every frame update.

I would appreciate if someone could look over the code and give suggestions on how to achieve the goal stated above. Later on I wanted to implement a GameManager but this is already getting very complex.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how `UpdateCoroutine2` gets called.

Comment: OK an event is like "OnClick", as a short version an Action is something that gets called as a result of the click (there are other reasons), so this isnt what you need at all.. and how you're calling  UpdateCoroutine2 isnt included in the code provided.. did you put it in update?

Comment: My attempts aren't in the listed code because they got very messy; I took them out and left the remainder of what I had. Yes, I put it in the Update function because I wasn't sure how to call something after the code is already running other than that. Well I did also try implementing *another* IEnumerator and calling `UpdateCoroutine2` when it reached a certain time but that also called it repeatedly for some reason. I'll try writing it up again how I had it in my last attempt but I don't know how I should try to change things.

Comment: It's calling repeatedly because it's in a `while` loop that repeats every fixed update for 3 seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using events here is really overcomplicating things for the thing you seem to want to do.

I would use [`yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) to time things:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public SkinnedMeshSpawn SkinnedMeshSpawn;

    void Start()
    { 
        StartCoroutine(FunctionCaller(3f,3f));
    }

    IEnumerator FunctionCaller(float pause1, float pause2)
    {
        SkinnedMeshSpawn.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshSpawn>().MoveCubes();

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(pause1);

        SkinnedMeshSpawn.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshSpawn>().LerpSine();

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(pause2);

        // Do whatever after pause 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes way more sense.